# Firebase Invites with OtherPlatform in iOS return page 404

Tags: android, ios, firebase-invites

I added in my Android app the Firebase App Invites. 
I set properly AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder append:

```
.setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication(AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder.PlatformMode.PROJECT_PLATFORM_IOS, "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
```

invitations are sent successfully, but if I open my mail with an iOS device, the link for the installation does not work!
They are directed to a Google Plus page with error 404.

---

**Solved**

I do not use deep links in my project, but Firebase, it also requires.
I added the line:

```
.setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_name)))
```

and invitations now also work in the other platform.